# brand section in wordpress lost after change theme

Tags: themes

i change my word press theme and my brand page (taxonomy and custom post type) got lost and its show me 404 . but i can see in my database

in older theme the path format was :
https://example.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=products_brand&post_type=product

in newer theme the path format is :
https://example.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=brand&post_type=product

how can I change **taxonomy=products_brand** to taxonomy=brand ?

I replaced this in all tables in my database but Yoast setting lost.

Comment: Brand was probably a feature of your old theme. It’s not something that’s part of WordPress. If you need to migrate data between two themes then you’ll need to speak to the theme authors. Third party themes are off topic here.

Comment: probably because the brand post type was defined in the theme not a plugin, as Jacob said you'll need to speak with the theme vendors, extracting theme functionality and migrating it to a new theme is not straight forward

Comment: @jacob-peattie  , The okder theme is encoded by theme author. I replaced the slug in database but brands in Yoast Seo setting (title , meta description of brands page) lost.